# how to transpose single column to obtain unique table

Tags: sql

I have a table that has member ID, month, and quantitative field. I would like to transpose the month field into columns so that I have a single row for each member. How can I transpose the month field into columns in SQL?

Current table:

| Mem ID | Month | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mem 1 | Jan | 20 |
| Mem 1 | Feb | 30 |
| Mem 1 | Mra | 20 |
| Mem 1 | April | 40 |
| Mem 2 | Jan | 20 |
| Mem 2 | Feb | 30 |
| Mem 2 | Mra | 20 |
| Mem 2 | April | 40 |

Desired table:

| Mem ID | Jan | Feb | Mar | April |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mem 1 | 20 | 30 | 20 | 40 |
| Mem 3 | 20 | 30 | 20 | 40 |

Not sure how to attempt this. I am using SQL (coginity) to do the data transformation.

Comment: Study `PIVOT` feature of your RDBMS.

Comment: What RDBMS? pivot, case expressions may work depending on database & version.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT MemID, Month, Total
  FROM your_table
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Total)
  FOR Month IN (Jan, Feb, Mar, April)
) AS p
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.